# What is the best way to save aol.com mail to a flashdrive?

Tags: windows, windows-live-mail

How do I save aol.com email to a flashdrive so when I want to view the message offline; all I would need to do is double click the email?  I was considering exporting it from the Windows Live Mail program.  When I tested this option, it compressed all the emails into one file which is not adventagous.  I then considered saving the individual emails from the email folder to the flashdrive, but the file names of the emails are not self explanitory and I will not know what that email contains.  So, What is the best way to save aol.com mail to a flashdrive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install [Thunderbird](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/) and setup your aol.com account in the account settings. Install the [ImportExport](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/mboximport-en.html) add-on select all messages and right-click go to "Save selected messages" Select the desired export format. EML in your case. Export to thumbdrive.

Comment: In this case, it might be easier to install [Thunderbird Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/thunderbird_portable) on the flash drive! :)

Comment: Even a better idea!

Comment: @ChristopherWilson Thank you!  That idea worked.